# Event handlers together with events in Haste

Tags: javascript, haskell

I'm testing out Haste-compiler, and I have a need for accessing the event and/or the originating element, but the `Event` type doesn't provide that information.

I tried making a ffi callback with the function below, but the 'event' it returns to the callback is undefined. What am I doing wrong, *or* is there a better approach using built-in functionality?

```
newtype EventCB = EventCB (JSAny -> IO ())

manualEvent :: Elem -> String -> (JSAny -> IO ()) -> IO ()
manualEvent e evt act = do
  f <- toCallback $ \evt' -> act evt'
  go e evt (EventCB f)
  where go = ffi $ toJSString "(function(e, evt, cb) {e.addEventListener(evt, cb);})"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just verified this to work for the click event:

```
listen :: JSType event => Elem -> event -> a -> IO Bool
listen e event f= jsSetCB e (toJSString event) (mkCallback $! f)
```

Called with

```
 listen  element  "click"   doit
```

and doit of type:

```
 doit :: Int -> (Int,Int) -> IO ()
```

using the perch library:

```
doit i (x,y)  = do
  body <- getBody
  (flip build) body $ do
     p i
     p (x,y)

  return()
```

listen is unsafe. You must make sure that the event handler have the right types of parameters.
The types for the known events are the ones of the used in onEvent

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the callback function use a reader monad for the event?  [Ghcjs-dom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcjs-dom) has a [connect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcjs-dom-0.1.0.0/docs/GHCJS-DOM-EventM.html) function that does this.  It looks like this...

```
connect :: (GObjectClass t, IsEvent e, ToDOMString string) => string -> t -> EventM e t () -> IO (IO ())
connect eventName target callback =
  eventTargetAddEventListener target eventName False $ curry (runReaderT callback)
```

The IO action returned can be used to remove the event listener when it is no longer needed.  eventTargetAddEventListener is [implemented](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcjs-dom-0.1.0.0/docs/src/GHCJS-DOM-EventTargetClosures.html#eventTargetAddEventListener) for both ghcjs and webkitgtk (so it works just as well in native Haskell apps as it does those compiled to JavaScript).

Please give [ghcjs](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs) a go if you have time.

Comment: I probably will give ghcjs a go again at some point, but it is still currently a bit too difficult to install and the files it creates are a bit big.

Comment: @Masse: it's now easier in my experience to get going with GHCJS than Haste; GHCJS works well with sandboxes (unlike Haste) and installs in a few simple steps.